# How To Declare Array Of Objects Globally In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that I'm using in multiple places in my component.ts file and I want to know how I can declare it globally or somehow turn it into it's own static class.

```
  calculateStandard(change) {
/* this function calculates the standard change for a transaction (most efficent denominations) */
// TODO make the denominations object a global variable or model
var denominations = [
  {name: "twenty", plural: "twenties", value: 20.00},
  {name: "ten", plural: "tens", value: 10.00},
  {name: "five", plural: "fives", value: 5.00},
  {name: "one", plural: "ones", value: 1.00},
  {name: "quarter", plural: "quarters", value: 0.25},
  {name: "dime", plural: "dimes", value: 0.10},
  {name: "nickle", plural: "nickles", value: 0.05},
  {name: "penny", plural: "pennies", value: 0.01}
];
var result = denominations.reduce(function(accumulator, currentDenomination) {   // iterates through the denomination object from top to bottom
  if (change >= currentDenomination.value) {
    var currentValue = 0.00;    // the amount of coins/bills for each denomination
    while (change >= currentDenomination.value) {
      currentValue ++;
      change -= currentDenomination.value;
      change = Math.round(change * 100) / 100   // prevents nasty decimal issues in TypeScript
    }
    if (currentValue > 1) {   // checks to see if the plural denomination name should be used or not
      accumulator.push({name: currentDenomination.plural, amount: currentValue});
    } else {
      accumulator.push({name: currentDenomination.name, amount: currentValue});
    }
    return accumulator;
  } else {
    return accumulator;
  }
}, []);   // the empty array is the initial accumulator
return result
}
```

the `denominations` object is the object I'm trying to declare globally.

Comment: check https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a static data and want to use it globally - There is a simplest way to implement it

You can also refer to this [Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-global-denomination)

**1.) Create denominations.ts - that exports your static data**

```
export const denominations = [
  {name: "twenty", plural: "twenties", value: 20.00},
  {name: "ten", plural: "tens", value: 10.00},
  {name: "five", plural: "fives", value: 5.00},
  {name: "one", plural: "ones", value: 1.00},
  {name: "quarter", plural: "quarters", value: 0.25},
  {name: "dime", plural: "dimes", value: 0.10},
  {name: "nickle", plural: "nickles", value: 0.05},
  {name: "penny", plural: "pennies", value: 0.01}
];
```

**2.) On your AppModule - import your denomination and specify it to the providers section**

```
// Import the newly create 'denominations.ts' as per step #1
import { denominations } from './denominations';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ 
    // Named the provide to 'DENOMINATIONS' which holds the denominations data
    { provide: 'DENOMINATIONS', useValue: denominations }   
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**3.) On your AppComponent - Inject the denomination and utilize it on your template**

> You can perform the @Inject method to any component you wish to utilize your static data

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{ denominations | json }}`,  // Or *ngFor to loop the data.
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(@Inject('DENOMINATIONS') public denominations: any[]) {
       // or try to console the denominations here
  }

}
```

Comment: If I want to write/edit data in denominations.ts, how do i do that?

Comment: You may not be able to directly change the data inside the denominations.ts if you are accessing it on another component through the @Inject() but you can use a service like you can name it as DenominationService and there you could perform any data manipulation based on what methods you want it to use that the other components will be able to utilize